# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class JInputCookie in /home3/trekperu/public_html/libraries/rokcommon/RokCommon/ClassLoader.php on line 98

Tags: joomla

This is the code:

```
<?php
defined('JPATH_PLATFORM') or die;
class JInputCookie extends JInput
{

    public function __construct(array $source = null, array $options = array())
    {
        if (isset($options['filter']))
        {
            $this->filter = $options['filter'];
        }
        else
        {
            $this->filter = JFilterInput::getInstance();
        }

        // Set the data source.
        $this->data = & $_COOKIE;

        // Set the options for the class.
        $this->options = $options;
    }

    public function set($name, $value, $expire = 0, $path = '', $domain = '', $secure = false, $httpOnly = false)
    {
        if (is_array($value))
        {
            foreach ($value as $key => $val)
            {
                setcookie($name . "[$key]", $val, $expire, $path, $domain, $secure, $httpOnly);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            setcookie($name, $value, $expire, $path, $domain, $secure, $httpOnly);
        }
        $this->data[$name] = $value;
    }
}
```

I dont find anything wrong. Lines 83 - 99 are:

```
public function set($name, $value, $expire = 0, $path = '', $domain = '', $secure = false, $httpOnly = false)
    {
        if (is_array($value))
        {
            foreach ($value as $key => $val)
            {
                setcookie($name . "[$key]", $val, $expire, $path, $domain, $secure, $httpOnly);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            setcookie($name, $value, $expire, $path, $domain, $secure, $httpOnly);
        }
        $this->data[$name] = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you give us more context? What is the code suppose to do? Do you have any leads?

Answer (score 0):

This is a lazy solution, but it'll work:

```
if (!class_exists('JInputCookie')) {
    class JInputCookie extends JInput{
        ...
    }
}
```

Essentially, you are telling PHP to only define the class `JInputCookie` if it is not already defined.